# Integration of PHP into JavaScript to take value from Backend

Tags: javascript, php

So what I am trying to do is take a input value from Backend(CMS like a wordpress, just that mine is a custom developed CMS) and display that value in a javascript code.

Taking values from backend code:

```
<?php 
   $effects_array=array( "sliceDown","sliceDownLeft", "sliceUp", 
                        "sliceUpLeft","sliceUpDown","sliceUpDownLeft",
                        "fold","fade","random","slideInRight",
                        "slideInLeft","boxRandom","boxRain","boxRainReverse",
                        "boxRainGrow","boxRainGrowReverse");
   foreach ($effects_array as $effects_key => $effect_value) {

?>
<label class="inline"><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $effect_value ?>" class="input-xxlarge" name="theme_options[effects_select]" <?php  if (isset($SITE['tmp']['dataList']->effects_select)){ ?> checked <?php } ?> ><?php echo $effect_value ?></label>
<?php
    }
?>
```

The code where I am trying to integrate:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({

        effect: '<?php echo $SITE['theme_options']['effects_select']->$effects_value ?>',
```

I need to have values from that effects_array to the **effect**

This is the error that I get when I inspect element

```
    $(window).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({

            effect: '<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\limetraycms\themes\amalfi_latest\home.tpl.php</b> on line <b>135</b><br />
```

Comment: one of the `$SITE['theme_options']['effects_select']` is not an array but really an object. You could `print_r($SITE)` to see what type it is. Or just try `$SITE->theme_options['effects_select']`,  `$SITE['theme_options']->effects_select` or `$SITE->theme_options->effects_select` to see if the error goes away with one of them.

Comment: I got the solution to the answer. It was that I displayed wrong array; it should have been `$SITE['theme_options']->effects_select`

Comment: You dont specify what the `$SITE` data structure looks like. **That would help a lot as its the target of the error message**

Comment: @JonathanKuhn By the way how do I close this question??

Comment: @RiggsFolly Stackoverflow will actually overflow if I specify the structure of $SITE. Anyways, I got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the `$SITE['theme_options']['effects_select']` is not an array but really an object. You could print_r($SITE) to see what type it is. Or just try one of:

- $SITE->theme_options['effects_select']
- $SITE['theme_options']->effects_select
- $SITE->theme_options->effects_select

to see if the error goes away with one of them.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it might be the quotes are all single quotes in the `effect:` line.

Either try this:

```
// using double quotes on the outside
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({

        effect: "<?php echo $SITE['theme_options']['effects_select']->$effects_value ?>",
```

or this:

```
// escaping the single quotes inside the outer single quotes
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({

        effect: '<?php echo $SITE[\'theme_options\'][\'effects_select\']->$effects_value ?>',
```

Comment: The quotes inside of a php statement won't affect the quotes outside of the php tags.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn is the same for Javascript?

Comment: Javascript won't even see the quotes in php, JS is client side, it will see the output of the echo statement.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Ah, good point. The PHP code will be executed before this gets to the client, so the quotes inside the PHP tags are irrelevant. Thanks for pointing that out.